# Why does co-locating data use so much storage space?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scdpm, system-center

I'm currently evaluating Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager 2010.

When creating a new protection group, I can select to co-locate the client data in the storage pool.

[image]

Now, the documentation states:

> System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM) allows you to co-locate your protection groups on a volume or tape. Co-locating your protection groups **allows you to use your storage more effectively**.

Awesome! So, let's enable it.

[image]

Now I require almost 10x as much storage space. Why?

Comment: I was unable to find any Data Protection Manager tag and can't create one either. A little help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I found the scdpm tag-- that's not exactly the easiest name to find, and its worthless for google. I'll write a meta post asking for re-name suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dpmstorage/thread/9d528f42-af07-4d8e-9e9a-738e7ec21088/) on Microsoft's forums, it is to do with the initial setup and configuration of co-location. Don't have a better source than it aside from the response is from a Microsoft Employee.

> When you configure client protection - in the PG wizard, it asks for the amount of data per client you expect to backup.  The Default for "Data per computer" is 5GB.    By default, DPM will co-locate 10 clients per Replica / Diff volume, so you will see by default DPM will allocate 61.56 GB the first time you create the PG.  This is assuming 10 clients at 5GB / client.